# c# datagridview having different datasources for different columns

Tags: c#, datasource, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview which has multiple text columns and a single comboboxcolumn. I need to specify a datasource for the iems of the comboboxcolumn and another datasource for the other text columns. I have tried the following sample code but it does not work.

```
dgv1.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables[0];
string[] managerList = Array.ConvertAll(DataSet2.Select(), row => (string)row[0]);
comboboxcolumn1.DataSource = managerList;
```

The managerList array has the entries that are to be populated into the combobox but they never show up.

Is that so that I can not have a separate datasource for a comboboxcolumn and its parent datagridview?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have.. have you tried using `BindingSource` while assigning to the combobox column

Comment: Could you be more specific? I could not find the bindingsource property for datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.

Comment: Its not a property , something like `comboboxcolumn1.DataSource = new BindingSource(managerList,null);`

Comment: I tried 
comboboxcolumn1.DataSource = new BindingSource(managerList, managerList[0]);

It says that datamember property '111111' cannot be found on the datasource. 111111 is the string in managerList[0]

Comment: so .. did that work .. any error ?

Comment: Well, with the null as the second argument, there is no exception thrown but the combobox is still empty. I am also trying to figure out why it is not working by assigning the datasource straightaway

Comment: @V4Vendetta Any ideas? My problem is still unsolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked with the following code and it works fine

```
string[] arr = "This Should Get Displayed".Split(); //managerList in your case           
dataGridView1.DataSource = MyData(false);
(dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = new BindingSource(arr, null); // Bind to the column of grid
```

Can you try assigning it as referencing it as a column of your datagridview.

This displays the text split on *space* in my combobox.

*When you are using string array no need to specify **Display** and **Value** member for the column*

**EDIT**

If you have a `DataTable` you can also do it in this fashion

```
(dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource= datatable;
(dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember="columnname";
(dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember="columnname";
```

Comment: This is still not working. Have you set the datasource of your datagridview to something else? Something that does not provide the data for the comboboxcolumn?

Comment: Yes .. currently the grid datasource has no relation for comboboxcolumn .. Do you have that in your case ?

Comment: I have created a working example wherein the comboboxcolumn gets the values from a subset of the values coming from a stored procedure. But handling 2 datasets seems to be a problem.

Comment: Sorry for that! Whats MyData(false) ?

Comment: In my example MyData is a method which set a `DataTable` as `DataSource` (some hard coded values)

Comment: Thanks for your time dude. Its still not working at my end though. I gues trying all that you have written out patiently should do the trick. I will mark it as the answer when I get it working. +10 for your time. :)